# SQL Server delete row by row and commit multiple record

Tags: sql-server, transactions, sql-server-2016

I have a scenario where I need to delete each row from a table but commit multiple rows at a time.

For example : I have a table `#temp1` where 100 records should be deleted. But after each 10 records deleted, I need to commit those 10 delete and so on. So after I have to commit 10 time to commit all 100 delete but loop 100 time to delete all 100 records.

I tried with loop and transaction. Sample below :

```
BEGIN TRANSACTION 
    While (@rowsdeleted <= @rowstodelete) 
    BEGIN 
      Delete records where condition is match 
      SET @deletedrows = @@rowcount  
    END
IF (deletedrows = 10)  
    BEGIN
      COMMIT TRANSACTION 
      SET deletedrows =0 
    END
```

This logic is committing only one row per commit. This will delete 10 records and when commit condition matched it commits only the last deleted record and other 9 records are not committed.

Do any one have any solution or logic to implement this issue ?

Comment: The best solution would be to stop doing deletes in a loop. Just delete the rows you want to delete. Using a loop for this is slow and pointless.

Comment: Looking closer at your code it is a nightmare. You are declaring transaction after transaction inside a loop.

Comment: @SeanLange I am using loop to delete each row because after I delete that row, i need to use other logics too which is not possible if I didn't use the loop.

Comment: @SeanLange I am declaring only one transaction but there can be few more logics / validation i might need to check.

Comment: Then why are you trying to do this strange commit every 10 rows logic? And no, your code has "BEGIN TRANSACTION" inside your loop. You have created yourself a nightmare here. If you have logic that is this complicated to delete a single row then you should probably create a stored procedure to handle all of that logic. Then call your procedure in a loop. Or better, revisit all this logic and make it so you don't have to jump through hoops to delete rows. Even cascading deletes would be better.

Comment: @SeanLange Updated the logic with transaction before loop.

Comment: Your logic continues to not make sense. The value of row count would change when you do your "other logic". Why not simply remove the explicit transaction here and just delete the row(s)?

Comment: `SET @deletedrows = @@rowcount` should probably be `SET @deletedrows += @@rowcount` Although I agree this logic is convoluted. Whatever you are doing can probably be done in one statement, but you haven't shown us your full code

Comment: @Charlieface This is weird requirement I got and I am focusing on having best query possible to complete this requirement. I know we can delete all the records in one query but I have to loop each record from the table. I am wondering the commit as multiple commit might give good performance.

Comment: No, the fastest (as single deletes) is doing a single `BEGIN TRAN;` before and a single `COMMIT;` after the loop. A commit needs to harden the transaction log to disk, which causes extra latency, so you want to push that off til afterwards

Answer (score 2):

```
declare 
    @check_tran int, 
    @deletedrows int, 
    @total_deletedrows int, 
    @max_delete int 
begin
    set @max_delete = 100; 
    
    set @check_tran = 0
    set @total_deletedrows =0
    
    BEGIN TRANSACTION
    
    While (@total_deletedrows <= @max_delete) 
    BEGIN 
        
        Delete records where condition is match 

        SET @deletedrows = @@rowcount
        SET @check_tran = @check_tran + @deletedrows
        SET @total_deletedrows = @total_deletedrows + @deletedrows  
        print @deletedrows
    
        if (@check_tran >= 10) 
        begin 
            COMMIT TRANSACTION
            SET @check_tran = 0 
            BEGIN TRANSACTION
        end
    END

    -- when record count of table will be 105 records then 5 records are not be commited
    -- so if transaction count > 0 then commit transaction 
    if (@@TRANCOUNT>0) 
    begin
        COMMIT TRANSACTION
    end 
end
```